# jquery ui dilog close clickout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I create jQuery UI daialog, if it is showed, when I click out it close

```
  $('#myDial').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 230,
        height: 170,
        modal: false,
        open: function() {
            window.closedialog = 1;
            $(document).bind('click', function(){
                if (window.closedialog) {
                    $('#myDial').dialog('close');
                }
                //set to one because click on dialog box sets to zero
                window.closedialog = 1;
            });
        },
        focus: function() {
            window.closedialog = 0;
        },
        close: function() {
            $(document).unbind('click');
        }

    })
```

ok.

My question : does exists any method or option for **dialog** to close it when I click out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery context menu for it

https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu

Answer (score 0):

This functionality makes sense to me only with modal dialogs. You can use the click-event on the overlay surrounding the dialog:

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').on("click", function() {
    $(document).find(".dialog").dialog("close");
});
```